# Is there a reference for how to add custom keymaps to operators in an addon?

Tags: interface, add-on

The Blender API is horribly convoluted, when it comes to actually being able to find any valuable examples or reference code for how to implement features when developing an addon.

Is there a reference that can help with how to implement custom keymaps in an addon?

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I poached some examples from other people's addons and made an addon myself, writing this up as a [keymap reference documentation](https://github.com/brybalicious/toggle_mmb_numpad/blob/master/keymap_implementation.md#key-types) to help myself during the process. Hopefully it can help some others...

## Notes and Reference for implementing keymaps in Blender Addons

### Valuable Resources:

- Space Type Reference [bpy.types.KeyMap.name](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMap.html?highlight=key%20name#bpy.types.KeyMap.name)
- Keymap Constructor incl. Space Type and Region Type Reference [bpy.types.KeyMaps.new](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMaps.html#bpy.types.KeyMaps.new)
- Key Type, Map Type and Value Reference [bpy.types.KeyMapItem.name](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMapItem.html?highlight=key%20name#bpy.types.KeyMapItem.name)
- How to extract [keymap names](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/official-keymap-example-does-not-work/9032/6)

### Example

- See the [Keymap Code](https://github.com/brybalicious/toggle_mmb_numpad/blob/b212cd3869483dbe7e2cb9c210f2676a35b1b8ff/__init__.py#L35) section of the `__init__.py` script for a working example
- Note, not all use cases are covered. This is a primer to begin to make sense of things

### Keymap Names

For Keymaps to show in their corresponding location in the [Edit >> Preferences >> Keymap] ui in Blender, keymap name must be identical to one of the following 224 strings (without the number), surrounded by quotes. E.g. "Window":

0    Window

1    Screen

2    Screen Editing

3    User Interface

4    View2D

5    Region Context Menu

6    View2D Buttons List

7    Frames

8    Property Editor

9    Outliner

10    Markers

11    Time Scrub

12    Animation

13    Dopesheet

14    Dopesheet Generic

15    3D View Generic

16    Grease Pencil

17    Grease Pencil Stroke Edit Mode

18    Grease Pencil Stroke Paint Mode

19    Grease Pencil Stroke Paint (Draw brush)

20    Grease Pencil Stroke Paint (Erase)

21    Grease Pencil Stroke Paint (Fill)

22    Grease Pencil Stroke Paint (Tint)

23    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt Mode

24    Grease Pencil Stroke Vertex Mode

25    Grease Pencil Stroke Vertex (Draw)

26    Grease Pencil Stroke Vertex (Blur)

27    Grease Pencil Stroke Vertex (Average)

28    Grease Pencil Stroke Vertex (Smear)

29    Grease Pencil Stroke Vertex (Replace)

30    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Smooth)

31    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Thickness)

32    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Strength)

33    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Grab)

34    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Push)

35    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Twist)

36    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Pinch)

37    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Randomize)

38    Grease Pencil Stroke Sculpt (Clone)

39    Grease Pencil Stroke Weight Mode

40    Grease Pencil Stroke Weight (Draw)

41    Paint Face Mask (Weight, Vertex, Texture)

42    Paint Vertex Selection (Weight, Vertex)

43    Weight Paint

44    Vertex Paint

45    Pose

46    Object Mode

47    Paint Curve

48    Curve

49    Image Paint

50    Sculpt

51    Mesh

52    Armature

53    Metaball

54    Lattice

55    Particle

56    Font

57    Object Non-modal

58    3D View

59    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Tweak

60    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Select Box

61    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Select Circle

62    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Select Lasso

63    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Cursor

64    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Rip Region

65    3D View Tool: Pose, Breakdowner

66    3D View Tool: Pose, Push

67    3D View Tool: Pose, Relax

68    3D View Tool: Edit Armature, Roll

69    3D View Tool: Edit Armature, Bone Size

70    3D View Tool: Edit Armature, Bone Envelope

71    3D View Tool: Edit Armature, Extrude

72    3D View Tool: Edit Armature, Extrude to Cursor

73    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Extrude Region

74    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Extrude Manifold

75    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Extrude Along Normals

76    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Extrude Individual

77    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Extrude to Cursor

78    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Inset Faces

79    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Bevel

80    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Loop Cut

81    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Offset Edge Loop Cut

82    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Knife

83    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Bisect

84    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Poly Build

85    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Spin

86    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Spin Duplicates

87    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Smooth

88    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Randomize

89    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Edge Slide

90    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Vertex Slide

91    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Shrink/Fatten

92    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Push/Pull

93    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, To Sphere

94    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Rip Region

95    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Rip Edge

96    3D View Tool: Edit Curve, Draw

97    3D View Tool: Edit Curve, Extrude

98    3D View Tool: Edit Curve, Extrude to Cursor

99    3D View Tool: Edit Curve, Radius

100    3D View Tool: Edit Curve, Tilt

101    3D View Tool: Edit Curve, Randomize

102    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Box Mask

103    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Lasso Mask

104    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Box Hide

105    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Mesh Filter

106    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Cloth Filter

107    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Color Filter

108    3D View Tool: Sculpt, Mask By Color

109    3D View Tool: Paint Weight, Gradient

110    3D View Tool: Paint Weight, Sample Weight

111    3D View Tool: Paint Weight, Sample Vertex Group

112    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Cutter

113    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Eyedropper

114    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Line

115    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Polyline

116    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Arc

117    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Curve

118    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Box

119    3D View Tool: Paint Gpencil, Circle

120    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Tweak

121    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Select Box

122    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Select Circle

123    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Select Lasso

124    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Extrude

125    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Radius

126    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Bend

127    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Shear

128    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, To Sphere

129    3D View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Transform Fill

130    3D View Tool: Edit Mesh, Make Line

131    3D View Tool: Hops

132    3D View Tool: Hardflow

133    3D View Tool: BoxCutter

134    3D View Tool: Cad Transform

135    Gizmos

136    Generic Gizmo

137    Generic Gizmo Maybe Drag

138    Generic Gizmo Tweak Modal Map

139    View3D Gesture Circle

140    Gesture Box

141    Gesture Zoom Border

142    Gesture Straight Line

143    Header

144    Standard Modal Map

145    Animation Channels

146    Knife Tool Modal Map

147    Custom Normals Modal Map

148    Bevel Modal Map

149    UV Editor

150    Paint Stroke Modal

151    Mask Editing

152    Eyedropper Modal Map

153    Eyedropper ColorRamp PointSampling Map

154    Transform Modal Map

155    View3D Fly Modal

156    View3D Walk Modal

157    View3D Rotate Modal

158    View3D Move Modal

159    View3D Zoom Modal

160    View3D Dolly Modal

161    View3D Placement Modal Map

162    Graph Editor Generic

163    Graph Editor

164    Image Generic

165    Image

166    Node Generic

167    Node Editor

168    Info

169    File Browser

170    File Browser Main

171    File Browser Buttons

172    NLA Generic

173    NLA Channels

174    NLA Editor

175    Text Generic

176    Text

177    SequencerCommon

178    Sequencer

179    SequencerPreview

180    Console

181    Clip

182    Clip Editor

183    Clip Graph Editor

184    Clip Dopesheet Editor

185    Clip Time Scrub

186    Generic Gizmo Drag

187    Generic Gizmo Click Drag

188    Generic Gizmo Select

189    Toolbar Popup

190    Generic Tool: Annotate

191    Generic Tool: Annotate Line

192    Generic Tool: Annotate Polygon

193    Generic Tool: Annotate Eraser

194    Image Editor Tool: Sample

195    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Sculpt Stroke

196    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Move

197    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Rotate

198    Image Editor Tool: Uv, Scale

199    Node Tool: Tweak

200    Node Tool: Select Box

201    Node Tool: Select Lasso

202    Node Tool: Select Circle

203    Node Tool: Links Cut

204    3D View Tool: Cursor

205    3D View Tool: Tweak

206    3D View Tool: Select Box

207    3D View Tool: Select Circle

208    3D View Tool: Select Lasso

209    3D View Tool: Transform

210    3D View Tool: Move

211    3D View Tool: Rotate

212    3D View Tool: Scale

213    3D View Tool: Shear

214    3D View Tool: Measure

215    3D View Tool: Object, Add Primitive

216    3D View Tool: Sculpt Gpencil, Tweak

217    3D View Tool: Sculpt Gpencil, Select Box

218    3D View Tool: Sculpt Gpencil, Select Circle

219    3D View Tool: Sculpt Gpencil, Select Lasso

220    Sequencer Tool: Select

221    Sequencer Tool: Select Box

222    Sequencer Tool: Blade

223    Sequencer Tool: Sample

- The above References are spat out by blender scripting console when running:

```
    import bpy
    for i, km in enumerate(bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.default.keymaps):
        print(f"{i}\t{km.name}")
```

- Note, these refer to what context one's cursor must be in during a Blender session, for key presses to actually activate. If, for example "User Interface" is used, the hotkey will only activate anything when the cursor is hovering over a user interface panel (not e.g. the 3D viewport). If, for example "Window", the hotkey will activate anywhere within the Blender application window

### Region Types

region_type must be one of the following references:

[‘WINDOW’, ‘HEADER’, ‘CHANNELS’, ‘TEMPORARY’, ‘UI’, ‘TOOLS’, ‘TOOL_PROPS’, ‘PREVIEW’, ‘HUD’, ‘NAVIGATION_BAR’, ‘EXECUTE’, ‘FOOTER’, ‘TOOL_HEADER’], default ‘WINDOW’, (readonly)

### Map Types

map_type must be one of the following references:

{'KEYBOARD_MODIFIER', 'KEYBOARD', 'MOUSE_WHEEL', 'MOUSE_GESTURE', 'MOUSE_BUTTON', 'MOUSE', 'NDOF', 'TWEAK', 'ACTIONZONE'}, (optional)

### Space Types

space_type must be one of the following, where the left-side CAPS is the reference. Use the reference in your code:

```
EMPTY Empty.

VIEW_3D 3D Viewport, Manipulate objects in a 3D environment.

IMAGE_EDITOR UV/Image Editor, View and edit images and UV Maps.

NODE_EDITOR Node Editor, Editor for node-based shading and compositing tools.

SEQUENCE_EDITOR Video Sequencer, Video editing tools.

CLIP_EDITOR Movie Clip Editor, Motion tracking tools.

DOPESHEET_EDITOR Dope Sheet, Adjust timing of keyframes.

GRAPH_EDITOR Graph Editor, Edit drivers and keyframe interpolation.

NLA_EDITOR Nonlinear Animation, Combine and layer Actions.

TEXT_EDITOR Text Editor, Edit scripts and in-file documentation.

CONSOLE Python Console, Interactive programmatic console for advanced editing and script development.

INFO Info, Log of operations, warnings and error messages.

TOPBAR Top Bar, Global bar at the top of the screen for global per-window settings.

STATUSBAR Status Bar, Global bar at the bottom of the screen for general status information.

OUTLINER Outliner, Overview of scene graph and all available data-blocks.

PROPERTIES Properties, Edit properties of active object and related data-blocks.

FILE_BROWSER File Browser, Browse for files and assets.

PREFERENCES Preferences, Edit persistent configuration settings.
```

### Key Types

Available keys and their references can be seen [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMapItem.html?highlight=key%20name#bpy.types.KeyMapItem.name), where the left-side CAPS is the reference, for the colloquial key name on the right-side. Use the reference in your code:

```
NONE Undocumented

LEFTMOUSE Left Mouse, LMB

MIDDLEMOUSE Middle Mouse, MMB

RIGHTMOUSE Right Mouse, RMB

BUTTON4MOUSE Button4 Mouse, MB4

BUTTON5MOUSE Button5 Mouse, MB5

BUTTON6MOUSE Button6 Mouse, MB6

BUTTON7MOUSE Button7 Mouse, MB7

PEN Pen

ERASER Eraser

MOUSEMOVE Mouse Move, MsMov

INBETWEEN_MOUSEMOVE In-between Move, MsSubMov

TRACKPADPAN Mouse/Trackpad Pan, MsPan

TRACKPADZOOM Mouse/Trackpad Zoom, MsZoom

MOUSEROTATE Mouse/Trackpad Rotate, MsRot

MOUSESMARTZOOM Mouse/Trackpad Smart Zoom, MsSmartZoom

WHEELUPMOUSE Wheel Up, WhUp

WHEELDOWNMOUSE Wheel Down, WhDown

WHEELINMOUSE Wheel In, WhIn

WHEELOUTMOUSE Wheel Out, WhOut

EVT_TWEAK_L Tweak Left, TwkL

EVT_TWEAK_M Tweak Middle, TwkM

EVT_TWEAK_R Tweak Right, TwkR

A A

B B

C C

D D

E E

F F

G G

H H

I I

J J

K K

L L

M M

N N

O O

P P

Q Q

R R

S S

T T

U U

V V

W W

X X

Y Y

Z Z

ZERO 0

ONE 1

TWO 2

THREE 3

FOUR 4

FIVE 5

SIX 6

SEVEN 7

EIGHT 8

NINE 9

LEFT_CTRL Left Ctrl, CtrlL

LEFT_ALT Left Alt, AltL

LEFT_SHIFT Left Shift, ShiftL

RIGHT_ALT Right Alt, AltR

RIGHT_CTRL Right Ctrl, CtrlR

RIGHT_SHIFT Right Shift, ShiftR

OSKEY OS Key, Cmd

APP Application, App

GRLESS Grless

ESC Esc

TAB Tab

RET Return, Enter

SPACE Spacebar, Space

LINE_FEED Line Feed

BACK_SPACE Backspace, BkSpace

DEL Delete, Del

SEMI_COLON ;

PERIOD .

COMMA ,

QUOTE “

ACCENT_GRAVE `

MINUS -

PLUS +

SLASH /

BACK_SLASH \

EQUAL =

LEFT_BRACKET [

RIGHT_BRACKET ]

LEFT_ARROW Left Arrow, ←

DOWN_ARROW Down Arrow, ↓

RIGHT_ARROW Right Arrow, →

UP_ARROW Up Arrow, ↑

NUMPAD_2 Numpad 2, Pad2

NUMPAD_4 Numpad 4, Pad4

NUMPAD_6 Numpad 6, Pad6

NUMPAD_8 Numpad 8, Pad8

NUMPAD_1 Numpad 1, Pad1

NUMPAD_3 Numpad 3, Pad3

NUMPAD_5 Numpad 5, Pad5

NUMPAD_7 Numpad 7, Pad7

NUMPAD_9 Numpad 9, Pad9

NUMPAD_PERIOD Numpad ., Pad.

NUMPAD_SLASH Numpad /, Pad/

NUMPAD_ASTERIX Numpad *, Pad*

NUMPAD_0 Numpad 0, Pad0

NUMPAD_MINUS Numpad -, Pad-

NUMPAD_ENTER Numpad Enter, PadEnter

NUMPAD_PLUS Numpad +, Pad+

F1 F1

F2 F2

F3 F3

F4 F4

F5 F5

F6 F6

F7 F7

F8 F8

F9 F9

F10 F10

F11 F11

F12 F12

F13 F13

F14 F14

F15 F15

F16 F16

F17 F17

F18 F18

F19 F19

F20 F20

F21 F21

F22 F22

F23 F23

F24 F24

PAUSE Pause

INSERT Insert, Ins

HOME Home

PAGE_UP Page Up, PgUp

PAGE_DOWN Page Down, PgDown

END End

MEDIA_PLAY Media Play/Pause, >/||

MEDIA_STOP Media Stop, Stop

MEDIA_FIRST Media First, |<<

MEDIA_LAST Media Last, >>|

TEXTINPUT Text Input, TxtIn

WINDOW_DEACTIVATE Window Deactivate

TIMER Timer, Tmr

TIMER0 Timer 0, Tmr0

TIMER1 Timer 1, Tmr1

TIMER2 Timer 2, Tmr2

TIMER_JOBS Timer Jobs, TmrJob

TIMER_AUTOSAVE Timer Autosave, TmrSave

TIMER_REPORT Timer Report, TmrReport

TIMERREGION Timer Region, TmrReg

NDOF_MOTION NDOF Motion, NdofMov

NDOF_BUTTON_MENU NDOF Menu, NdofMenu

NDOF_BUTTON_FIT NDOF Fit, NdofFit

NDOF_BUTTON_TOP NDOF Top, Ndof↑

NDOF_BUTTON_BOTTOM NDOF Bottom, Ndof↓

NDOF_BUTTON_LEFT NDOF Left, Ndof←

NDOF_BUTTON_RIGHT NDOF Right, Ndof→

NDOF_BUTTON_FRONT NDOF Front, NdofFront

NDOF_BUTTON_BACK NDOF Back, NdofBack

NDOF_BUTTON_ISO1 NDOF Isometric 1, NdofIso1

NDOF_BUTTON_ISO2 NDOF Isometric 2, NdofIso2

NDOF_BUTTON_ROLL_CW NDOF Roll CW, NdofRCW

NDOF_BUTTON_ROLL_CCW NDOF Roll CCW, NdofRCCW

NDOF_BUTTON_SPIN_CW NDOF Spin CW, NdofSCW

NDOF_BUTTON_SPIN_CCW NDOF Spin CCW, NdofSCCW

NDOF_BUTTON_TILT_CW NDOF Tilt CW, NdofTCW

NDOF_BUTTON_TILT_CCW NDOF Tilt CCW, NdofTCCW

NDOF_BUTTON_ROTATE NDOF Rotate, NdofRot

NDOF_BUTTON_PANZOOM NDOF Pan/Zoom, NdofPanZoom

NDOF_BUTTON_DOMINANT NDOF Dominant, NdofDom

NDOF_BUTTON_PLUS NDOF Plus, Ndof+

NDOF_BUTTON_MINUS NDOF Minus, Ndof-

NDOF_BUTTON_ESC NDOF Esc, NdofEsc

NDOF_BUTTON_ALT NDOF Alt, NdofAlt

NDOF_BUTTON_SHIFT NDOF Shift, NdofShift

NDOF_BUTTON_CTRL NDOF Ctrl, NdofCtrl

NDOF_BUTTON_1 NDOF Button 1, NdofB1

NDOF_BUTTON_2 NDOF Button 2, NdofB2

NDOF_BUTTON_3 NDOF Button 3, NdofB3

NDOF_BUTTON_4 NDOF Button 4, NdofB4

NDOF_BUTTON_5 NDOF Button 5, NdofB5

NDOF_BUTTON_6 NDOF Button 6, NdofB6

NDOF_BUTTON_7 NDOF Button 7, NdofB7

NDOF_BUTTON_8 NDOF Button 8, NdofB8

NDOF_BUTTON_9 NDOF Button 9, NdofB9

NDOF_BUTTON_10 NDOF Button 10, NdofB10

NDOF_BUTTON_A NDOF Button A, NdofBA

NDOF_BUTTON_B NDOF Button B, NdofBB

NDOF_BUTTON_C NDOF Button C, NdofBC

ACTIONZONE_AREA ActionZone Area, AZone Area

ACTIONZONE_REGION ActionZone Region, AZone Region

ACTIONZONE_FULLSCREEN ActionZone Fullscreen, AZone FullScr
```

- Note the suggestions [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/keymap_editing.html#available-keys) and [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/industry_compatible.html) on generally available keys
- Also, see this visual reference for a map of all [default hotkeys](https://www.giudansky.com/illustration/infographics/blender-map#lg=1&slide=0)

### Value

"value" must be one of the following references, corresponding to the nature of the button press or tweak:

enum in [‘ANY’, ‘PRESS’, ‘RELEASE’, ‘CLICK’, ‘DOUBLE_CLICK’, ‘CLICK_DRAG’, ‘NORTH’, ‘NORTH_EAST’, ‘EAST’, ‘SOUTH_EAST’, ‘SOUTH’, ‘SOUTH_WEST’, ‘WEST’, ‘NORTH_WEST’, ‘NOTHING’], default ‘NOTHING’

---

**Hopefully this makes a little more sense of things, and helps you with creating your own basic addons**