# Shortcut Key to Pick Color on GreasePencil in vertex color mode

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to pick color quickly like texture paintMode color picker shortCut[S].

Default Hotkey color picker ( eye dropper ) on vertex color  is <kbd>E</kbd>, however, it is only work on menu vertex color menu not working on 3D view port while drawing.

It is slow to menu press <kbd>E</kbd> to pick vertex colors.

[image]

GreasePencil eyedropper shortCut also exits.

If I assign shortCut like <kbd>E</kbd> (and inactive other same key's shortCut),it works even in 3D view port on draw mode of GreasePencil, but greasePencil eyedropper could only pickcolor as adding material, or add color to pallet.
It cannot pick color as vertex.

I tried

Adding KeyMap of Eyedropper short cut of User Interface to GreasePencil(Global),GreasePencil Stroke Paint(Draw brush) in preference menu. But it does not work.

[image]

Reference

[Is there a reference for how to add custom keymaps to operators in an addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200811/is-there-a-reference-for-how-to-add-custom-keymaps-to-operators-in-an-addon)

https://blenderartists.org/t/grease-paint-eyedropper-in-vertex-paint-mode/1265552